# $wpdb->update Issue

Tags: plugin-development, database, wpdb

Can anyone see what I have wrong here?

```
$wpdb->update(
    $table, 
     array(
        'lat'=>$paper_lat,
        'lon'=>$paper_lon
    ), 
    array(
        'id'=> $result=>id
    ), 
    array(
        '%d',
        '%d'
    ), 
    array('%d')
);
```

This gives me a white screen. As far as I can tell I have the format correct according the the codex but it is giving me fits. I am sure that it is something simple but if someone would point it out to me I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) please.

Comment: You might want to turn on debugging to avoid that white screen. It makes life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array(
    'id'=> $result=>id
),
```

should be

```
array(
    'id'=> $result->id
),
```

I suspect that's your white screen issue.

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that. I looked and looked but couldn't see it. Thanks!